# Obj-C - Fire local notifications at specific times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm building a calendar app, and I want my users to be able to get notified 30 min before an appointment, or 60 minutes before an appointment. That said, how can I schedule a local notification to fire 30 min before a scheduled time pulled from an array or dictionary? My current code is able to fire a notification from the background at a specific time, but I'm not sure how to call the returned dates set by my user to App Delegate?

E.g. the array data coming from my server:

```
"Apr 14 2021 12:04 PM",
"Apr 17 2021 12:27 PM"
```

My code currently in app delegate:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
       NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
       NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:now];
       [components setHour:7];
       [components setMinute:00];

       UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
       notification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
       notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
       [notification setAlertBody:@"Ready to start your day?"];
       // notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    
    
}
```

Any help on how I should execute this is appreciated! I hope the way I explained what I'm trying to do makes sense.

Comment: You are setting the date components of the notification to 7 am. Have you tried to set the fireDate to the date you get from your server?

Comment: I'm able to do it with one date, but what if I have an array of dates that I want the notification to fire on? E.g. if Apr 2 2021 5:00 PM & Apr 14 2021 10:00 AM are returned in my array, how can I set the above code to fire at both times instead of just one ? @dasdom

Comment: You need a notification for every fire date.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM d yyyy h:mm a";

NSString *dtString = @"Apr 14 2021 12:04 PM";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dtString];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
components.minute -= 30;
NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Then use `fireDate` to set fireDate of notification. I suggest storing `dateFormatter` and `calendar` as static properties.

Comment: Super helpful - thank you! I was able to use this and loop through my array of times to schedule notifications for multiple days with dtstring :)